# How to prevent redirection while parsing

Tags: python, web-scraping, instagram

I'm parsing Instagram, and it started redirecting me to the login page.
The scrip is just taking stuff from the main page with no logging functionality. 
`- window._sharedData`

How can I stop it from redirecting and still keep loading the targeted account main page?

```
for i in list_of_urls:
        headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.87 Safari/537.36'}
        responce = requests.get(i,headers=headers)
        response_text = responce.text
        shared_data = response_text.split('window._sharedData = ')[1].split(';</script>')[0]
etc...
```

I've checked the redirections with:

```
for i in list_of_urls:
        headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.87 Safari/537.36'}
        responce = requests.get(i,headers=headers)
        if responce.history:
           print("Request was redirected")
        for resp in responce.history:
            print(resp.status_code, resp.url)
        print("Final destination:")
        print(responce.status_code, responce.url)
    else:
        print("Request was not redirected")
```

And it does redirect:

```
https://www.instagram.com/_linails_/
https://www.instagram.com/alena.nails.tallinn/
Request was redirected
302 https://www.instagram.com/_linails_/
Final destination:
200 https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/
Request was redirected
302 https://www.instagram.com/alena.nails.tallinn/
Final destination:
200 https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/
Request was not redirected
```

Any idea how to make it stop redirecting or get back without logging?

P.S.
looks like Instagram got the idea that it is a script opening the pages.
Here is the full response from it - https://yadi.sk/d/2vcng8VTBDz35A

Comment: For future, please do not use shorthand. You used the word `acc`, when you should have used `account`. `acc`, for all we know, could mean Austin Community College, so please in the future use the full word.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
>>> r = requests.get('<url>', allow_redirects=False)
```

**UPDATE: Fri 11 Oct 07:21:15 UTC 2019**

I can't reproduce this issue to see why there is no any content  I'm afraid, perhaps they're some restriction based on location:

```
>>> r = requests.get('https://www.instagram.com/_linails_/')
>>> r.history
[]
>>> r.url
'https://www.instagram.com/_linails_/'
```

Comment: Tryed it before and it is not working. I mean it does, no redirects, but Instagram does not return any content in this case.

Comment: Please see my update: `Fri 11 Oct 07:21:15 UTC 2019`

Comment: Looks like Instagram got the idea that this is a robot parsing them. @HTF 
Here  is the full response from Instagram on my requests -https://yadi.sk/d/2vcng8VTBDz35A

Comment: Since your "solution" isn't following the OP, what is ">>>" referencing? Is that just you pointing at what's there? And you didn't define "r". Can't reproduce this issue? Interesting statement. Just make sure you are logged out of Instagram and visit a page that you know. You will get re-directed to a login page. I used Chrome Inspector and they are using a javascript with (anonmous) and redirecting that way. I don't do much hacking or scraping so it's out of my experience. I program though.